# Brand New v. New Brand

Tags: difference

Brand New v. New Brand

What is the difference between “brand new” and “new brand”? I think  “brand new” represents a very new item or product just purchased, while “new brand” indicates a very new version of a product already on the market, or in circulation.

Comment: You have it right...

Answer (score 1):

In modern usage the phrases are a little confusing.

"Brand new" is usually used to refer to something that's recently acquired, particularly if it is new from the shop.

> I decided not to buy a used car and bought a brand new one from the dealership instead.

"New brand" more often refers to a company or product brand.

> Compared to other car manufacturers, Tesla is a relatively new brand.